# Date Filters and Group options do not appear

Tags: excel-2007, ssas, pivot-table

I am quite a new user, working on a pivot table with SQL Server Analysis Services on Windows Server 2003.

I am unable to filter my reports by date despite having Googled many websites for advice. A blog tells me that by grouping we can easily filter by date but whenever I group a single field (row) it automatically groups it with a new column. No row or column is empty, so I don’t understand why it does not show me the group dialogue box to set parameters manually and also on right click and hover over on filter. Only one filter option shows, "Top 10", however many other options I have seen in tutorials about filtering by date.

My date format is 2013-05-07 which I cannot change. Maybe this is the problem?

I just want to filter report by date. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, Its very disappointing that i can`t figureout it hitherto. No idea about how to change text format to date time. Kindly describe me or suggest me any link through which i can understand how to change text format.